# Vertical, right and bottom alignment; cross-browser

Tags: html, css

Sorry if I can't explain with code, I'm newbie with CSS. How can I do this?:

[image]

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>CSS DIV issue</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <img src="image-800x216.gif" />
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <img src="image-567x43.gif" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is intended to work with IE (all), Opera, Safari, Chrome and FF. Is possible or I'm dreamer?

Comment: Why not absolute positioning ? This would seem to be the easiest to achieve the same result as in the picture.

Comment: @Artefact2 I'd like to know enough about CSS to respond it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/XTkA2/30/

```
#div1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 38%;
    right: 1em;
    width: 62%;
    max-width: 50em;
    outline:#999 solid 1px;
}

#div2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.63em;
    right: 1em;
    width: 46%;
    max-width: 35.44em;
    outline:#999 solid 1px;
}
```

I've added `outline` for you to make `div`s visible. You may delete them.

Comment: Use the `outline` property for this sort of thing - `outline`s do not affect the layout of the element, unlike `border`. Oh, and you can use http://placehold.it for placeholder images

Comment: Thank you very much to @ted by the help to construct CSS code, to @YiJiang and @ŠimeVidas by the placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm...i don't understand what is your intention...but...do you want to align two images, one above another on the page center or one beside another or both images on right-bottom?

If you want to align elements in page, try this:

```
/* Both images aligned side-by-side at page center */
div.div1, div.div2
{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* One images at right, another at left */
div.div1
{
  float: left;
}

div.div2
{
  float: right;
}
```

Page bottom alignment is not possible...i guess.
Put you can use margin-top css property to do the trick.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good answer, although your code doesn't work as I expected, it helped me a lot to understand some strange things about alignment and floating properties.

Answer (score 0):

After applying and mixing your all helpful answers and hours and hours of reading and trying css/html code from different sites... I have what I want; well, almost in 95% due to browsers compatibility. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>CSS DIVs alignment issue</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #div1 {
      width:62%;
      min-width:16em;
      max-width:50em;
      right:1em;
      top:38%;
      margin-right:1em;
      height:auto;
      z-index:0;
      position:absolute;
    }
    #div2 {
      width:46%;
      min-width:10em;
      max-width:35.44em;
      right:1em;
      bottom:6%;
      margin-right:1em;
      height:auto;
      z-index:0;
      position:absolute;
    }
    .stretch {
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
      min-width:10em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/216" class="stretch" />
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/567/43" class="stretch" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

By the way, although I prefer [placehold.it](http://placehold.it) to [placekitten.com](http://placekitten.com) I use the last because the images must resize while screen does too.

You can check the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/quantik/Uk3CS/). (Thanks to [ted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654071/ted))